# Bug in a simplified (and incomplete) version of hangman game

Tags: c

I have written a first version of hangman. The game will be completed later, when this part of code will work.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



int main()
{
    char word[]={"name"};
    char word0[]={"----"};
    char lett;
    int i;
    int c;
    int e=0;

    while(e<12)
    {
        gotoxy(2,2);
        printf("\n%s\n",word0);
        scanf("%c",&lett);
        for(i=0,c=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if(lett==word[i])
            {
                word0[i]=word[i];
                c++;
            }
        }


        printf("%d",c);  
        if(c==0)
        {
            e++;
            printf("%d",e);
        }       
    }    
    printf("You lose");
    getchar();
}
```

The program ends before I make 12 errors and prints two values per cycle (not 1, which it should do) which don't coincide with the actual number of errors. Why?

Comment: sort out the indentation

Comment: I get inputs of the next character in the while loop!

Answer (score 0):

The second 'cycle', as you call it, is reading the newline character. Try changing your scanf to this:

```
scanf("%c\n",&lett);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But changing that, it doesn't individue some character in the word "name" 
and continues to print strange numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The second entry you get is the new line when you press, says, "a", then "Enter". The "Enter" is a new char which is then processed by your program.

Instead of using `scanf("%c",&lett);`, use `scanf(" %c",&lett);` (with a space before the '%' => this will ignore any spaces, new lines, etc.

Comment: Uhm...It goes better but It doesn't work correctly! it prints the number 1 when I enter the first character!
the same using getchar()

Comment: @user3210656 You are telling it to print the number of correct letters, `c`, on this line: `printf("%d",c);`. You might change that to `printf("correct letters = %d\n",c);`, or get rid of it altogether, since you print out word0 near the top of your loop.

Comment: It continues to prints ''random'' values...
and it prints "correct letters: " twice

if I elimine that code line (printf("%c",c)) it continues to print 1..

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes make the code work.
Note that I had to change the I/O a bit (don't have gotoxy() function, and no interactive input since I was running this on codepad.org). See where the logic of your code is different and you should have your solution.

I added intermediate printf statements so you can follow the flow more clearly - usually a good idea when you are debugging.

Note - you might want to use case insensitive string comparison...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[]="name";
    char word0[]="----";
    char guess[]="bnexacdfm";
    char lett;
    int i;
    int c;
    int e=0;
    int gi = 0;

    while(e<12 && gi < strlen(guess))
    {
//        gotoxy(2,2);
        printf("\n%s\n",word0);
        lett = guess[gi++];
        printf("you guessed: %c\n", lett);
// scanf("%c",&lett);
        for(i=0,c=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if(lett==word[i]) // really want case insensitive comparison here
            {
                word0[i]=word[i];
                printf("found %c at position %d\n", lett, i);
                c++;
            }
        }


        printf("Number correct in this guess: %d\n",c);  
        if(c==0)
        {
            e++;
            printf("Total number of incorrect guesses: %d\n",e);
        }       
    }    
    if(strcmp(word, word0)==0) {
      printf("well done! you win\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("Sorry - you lose\n");
    }
    return 0;
//    getchar();
}
```

Output:

```
----
you guessed: b
Number correct in this guess: 0
Total number of incorrect guesses: 1

----
you guessed: n
found n at position 0
Number correct in this guess: 1

n---
you guessed: e
found e at position 3
Number correct in this guess: 1

n--e
you guessed: x
Number correct in this guess: 0
Total number of incorrect guesses: 2

n--e
you guessed: a
found a at position 1
Number correct in this guess: 1

na-e
you guessed: c
Number correct in this guess: 0
Total number of incorrect guesses: 3

na-e
you guessed: d
Number correct in this guess: 0
Total number of incorrect guesses: 4

na-e
you guessed: f
Number correct in this guess: 0
Total number of incorrect guesses: 5

na-e
you guessed: m
found m at position 2
Number correct in this guess: 1
well done! you win
```

Link to code sample: http://codepad.org/56dC0stD